# Sending only required data subset to slaves in load-balancing case using Parallel package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

I'm using `parallel` package to distibute my calculations over a few nodes. Each atomic job is a calculation based on a subset from a data.table

The current solution looks like:

```r
library(parallel)
cluster_size = max(1, detectCores() - 1)
cl = makeCluster(cluster_size)
clusterExport(cl, c("dt"))
n_jobs = length(unique(dt$id))

job = function(i) {
  my_data = dt[id == i] #a few rows will correspond to a single job 'piece'

  res = do_calculations(my_data)
  return(res)
}

res = clusterApplyLB(cl, n_jobs, job)
res = rbindlist(res)
stopCluster(cl)
```

This sends *all* the data to each of the slaves, which is a waste of memory and speed because of transmission.
How can I optimize this to only send required subset of the `data.table` to slaves, when I do not know in advance which slave will execute which piece (load-balancing is a must)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to send only the required data to the workers, you should create a list of subsets of `dt` and iterate over that list using `clusterApplyLB`. For example:

```
ids = sort(unique(dt$id))
job = function(my_data) {
  do_calculations(my_data)
}
res = clusterApplyLB(cl, lapply(ids, function(i) dt[id == i]), job)
```

Now you don't export `dt` to the workers because the master is creating the subsets rather than the workers.